# porque se reemplaza el ultimo producto de mi array PHP

Tags: php, array

estoy creando un carrito de comprar por lo tanto cuando selecciono un 
 producto los productos los voy guardando en un array de una variable de sesión  , me deja agregar productos y también eliminarlos , pero solo si elimino el ultimo producto que agregue todo funciona bien  me deja agregar mas productos normal , pero si elimino un producto diferente al ultimo que agregue al intentar agregar un nuevo producto me reemplaza el ultimo

**asi los agrego**

```
<?php
session_start();
$Codigo = $_POST['Codigo']; 
$Nombre = $_POST['Nombre']; 
$Precio = $_POST['Precio']; 
$Talla = $_POST['Talla']; 
$Cantidad = $_POST['Cantidad']; 
if (!isset($_SESSION['carrito'])) {
   $prendas = array(
    'Codigo' => $Codigo,
    'Nombre' => $Nombre,
    'Precio' => $Precio,
    'Talla' => $Talla,
    'Cantidad' => $Cantidad
    );  
    $_SESSION['carrito'][0] = $prendas;
    $_SESSION['mensaje'] = "<span style='color:green;font-size: 18px'> La Prenda <b>"   .$Nombre ."</b> fue añadida al carrito.</span>";
    } else {

        $NumeroPrendas = count($_SESSION['carrito']);
        $prendas = array(
        'Codigo' => $Codigo,
        'Nombre' => $Nombre,
        'Precio' => $Precio,
        'Talla' => $Talla,
        'Cantidad' => $Cantidad
        );  
        $_SESSION['carrito'][$NumeroPrendas] = $prendas;
        $_SESSION['mensaje'] = "<span style='color:green;font-size: 18px'> La Prenda <b>"   .$Nombre ."</b> fuel añadida al carrito.</span>";
    }
    // }
    header("location:../prendas/inicio");

?>
```

**asi los elimino**

```
<?php
session_start();
    $Codigo = $_REQUEST['Codigo'];
    // $Nombre = $_REQUEST['Nombre'];
    echo $Codigo;
    foreach ($_SESSION['carrito'] as $indice => $prendas) {
        if ($prendas['Codigo'] ==  $Codigo ) {
                unset($_SESSION['carrito'][$indice]);
        } 
        $_SESSION['mensaje_eliminar'] = "La Prenda <b>"   .$Nombre ."</b> fue eliminada del carrito.";
        header("location:../mostrar-carrito");
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el problema creo es que por ejemplo si tienes dos elementos y eliminas el primero  el segundo elemento con indice 1 se sobreescribe ya que luego de eliminar entra al agregar y el count da 1 por tanto se sobreescribe, ya que el elemento que quedo luego de eliminar tiene indice 1.

**la solucion podria ser ordenar los indices del array luego de eliminar, lo que seria usar funcion array_values**

```
    $_SESSION['carrito']=array_values($_SESSION["carrito"]);
```

cabe destacar que el unset elimina el elemento del array pero no ordena los indices

Comment: Muchas gracias , esta era la solución.

Comment: @NeiiderMartinezRivas de nada suerte en tu desarollo.